# Spelling ability of different generations

Tags: data-request, education

I want to study how the spelling/grammar abilities of people has evolved over the ages.
I mean the ability to write down dictated text without making grammar/etc mistakes.

For instance, for a particular geographical area, do current 20 year olds spell worse or better than the 20 year olds of 2005, 1985, 1965, 1945, 1925, etc.

The more age groups, geographical areas, and languages the better.

Comment: Dication typically doesn't use spelling.  Nor grammer, as you're accurately recording what the person said.  You deal with those aspects when transcribing the dictation afterwards.  The goal is to let the person dictating to speak freely, without making them have to wait for you because you're too slow.  See http://www.keller.com/articles/readingspeed.html ; he mentions that people dictate to computers near 105wpm, but average typing speeds were closer to 40wpm (the link cites the studies that gathered these speeds; a bibliographic search might yield data closer to what you're asking for)

Comment: @Joe: Depends on the language. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictation_%28exercise%29: "For speakers of French, la dictée is a school exercise that aims at testing the mastery of orthography and grammar." Even in English, dictation is a way to tell who has understood it's/its for instance.